# What is a cut and paste approach to converting a chunk of a google spreadsheet to markdown table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, markdown, copy-paste

I maintain my web site in a version of markdown, with the common table extension.

I maintain my inventory as a google spreadsheet.

I'd like a quick way to copy paste a chunk of a spreadsheet, and get it out as markdown.  Failing that, pointers to a google-api script that does this.

In passing things I tried:
1.  Copy and paste into document.  (It works for gmail, why not?)  Result:  Alphabet soup.

2. Prepare a spreadsheet chain.  Sheet 1 is blank.  Sheet 2 has columns that reference sheet one, but Sheet2 col B references Sheet 1 col A Col D references B, and so on.  The odd columns are markdown text.  This works but is incredibly ugly.
3. A second version of this calculates the longest element in each column, and pads all other elements with blanks.  This produces better results, but it's still a pain to maintain.

A google search for google sheets markdown found several things that work badly.

Comment: What did you tried? Did you already looked at the documentation? What search terms did you used? Do you already look for an add-on that does the conversion to markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer is trivial:  Google webapps has

MarkdownTableMaker

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdowntablemaker/cofkbgfmijanlcdooemafafokhhaeold?hl=en

Works reasonably well.